# invisible recaptcha callback changed form value

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, recaptcha

I am now using google invisible recaptcha-v2. Code is running fine without any problem. Just a minor issue:

Original code:

```
const self = this;
execCaptcha('logincaptcha', function (res) {
   self.captchaRes = res;
   self.login();
});
```

Where the execCaptcha is my utility function to show captcha while passing div id and get response in callback.

The problem is I am using angular 5's form builder(not sure whether this could be the reason).

case 1: Let's say using userName: user1 and password: password1. If I modify it to password2 and submit. After the callback, the form value of password reverts back to 'password1'. I used a debugger to see the value and the value is indeed changed during this function.

case 2: while if I return the value directly(not waiting for the callback) for function execCaptcha, the form value does not change.

It seems the value was updated while waiting for recaptcha response.

How should I fix this issue? I tested in chrome, with "saved password" feature enabled.

Thank you.

Comment: You might consider using an arrow function instead of the `self = this` antipattern, that's one of the reasons arrow functions were created

Comment: do you mean: execCaptcha('logincaptcha', (res)=> {
   this.captchaRes = res;
   this.login();
}); I tried this as my first version, but not working. so i changed this "self" approach. May I know is it the suggestion for cause of the form reset? Thank you.

Comment: `but not working` You'll have to elaborate, but if your development environment doesn't support ES2015, strongly consider upgrading to something modern

Comment: thank you for your affirmation. I tried again, exact code working for arrow style as I typed above. thought maybe other thing broke last time. However, the password reset issue still exists. Any idea on that?